# Updating a model w/ Backbone.js + Rails not working (PUT route not found)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

In backbone.js I'm updating a category model:

```
@category.save {
  name : category_name,
}
```

This saves fine and updates the collection properly in backbone. But on the rails serverside its not saving because of a routing error:

```
Started PUT "/categories" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-24 11:18:16 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/categories"):
```

The problem is that rails expects PUT/update to have a url including the id "/categories/:id", not just "/categories"

I tested this out by changing the model url from:

```
class Category extends Backbone.Model
  name: 'category'
  url: ->
    host + '/categories'
```

to

```
class Category extends Backbone.Model
  name: 'category'
  url: ->
    host + '/categories/2'
```

This works fine.

```
Started PUT "/categories/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-24 11:44:08 -0400
  Processing by CategoriesController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"category"=>{"created_at"=>2010-03-14 16:30:07 -0400, "id"=>2, "name"=>"Lunchr5", "updated_at"=>2010-03-14 16:30:07 -0400, "user_id"=>1}, "api_key"=>"s1boakDIav30V6DzOFsY", "id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`single_access_token` = 's1boakDIav30V6DzOFsY' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  AREL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `visit_count` = 11, `perishable_token` = 'YG3s4yB01FxUMdMcK8m', `updated_at` = '2011-05-24 15:44:08' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
  SQL (0.3ms)  COMMIT
  Option Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `options`.* FROM `options` WHERE (`options`.user_id = 1) LIMIT 1
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Category Load (13.1ms)  SELECT `categories`.`id` FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`user_id` = 1 AND (`categories`.`name` = BINARY 'Lunchr5') AND (`categories`.id <> 2) LIMIT 1
  AREL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `categories` SET `name` = 'Lunchr5', `updated_at` = '2011-05-24 15:44:09' WHERE `categories`.`id` = 2
  SQL (0.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/categories
Completed 302 Found in 179ms
```

Do I have to hack backbone to add the :id to the url or am I missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Backbone will determine the url to use from the result of Model.url(). So if you have

```
class Category extends Backbone.Model
    name: 'category'
    url: ->
        host + '/categories'
```

The url backbone's save method will try on the server will be: host+'/categories'

If you do not define a url function, the default behaviour for the url function will delegate to the collection that it is in. So if you have a collection

```
class Categories extends Backbone.Collection
    model:Category
    url: ->
        host + '/categories'
class Category extends Backbone.Model
    name: 'category'
```

and instance of Category that belongs to a Categories collection will automatically get use the url host+'/categories'+'/'+category.id to save to the server.

Now if your model is not part of a collection, then you can't do this. You have to override the url function in your model so something like this

```
class Category extends Backbone.Model
    name: 'category'
    url: ->
        u = "#{host}/categories/"
        u = "#{u}#{this.id}" if this.id
        u
```

**Note** that this is not hacking. This is using backbone correctly. In fact in future editions of backbone, I believe there will be no default behaviour of the url function, and the url function will have to be written for all Models.

Comment: +1 for a great answer. This stuff should be explained clearly in the docs, or in a "best practices" section of the wiki.

Comment: I'm surprised really. Just to confirm, you would have to always write this `u =` chain if you wanted to implement a PUT request? That seems a bit undry.

Answer (score 1):

When using a model outside of a collection, provide a url root:

```
class Category extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: '/categories'
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot

Answer (score 0):

If your category is present on the server side, then you category object should have an ID and everything just work. From the code you sent, the id was not set:

```
@category.save {
  name : category_name
}
```

add the ID when instantiating the category and it should be ok otherwise backbone will try to create the category on the backend with a POST. If you specify the ID it will do a PUT. That is if you setup a collection for your object.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync

Comment: I did actually try including an ID in the params { id : @category.get('id') }, but that didn't help.

Comment: Your category does have an id or not? Putting it in the save params will not help. It only needs to be set on the model.

Comment: Then show us the whole code. If you use a function for url, backbone will not do any magic i think. Why do you specify the host? It will use the window.location host